# MKAnnotationView not displaying the title

Tags: iphone, xcode, mkmapview, mkannotationview, callouts

I am setting the title for two `MKAnnotationView` using the following code:

```
-(MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mV viewForAnnotation:
(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation 
{

if(([annotation isKindOfClass:[Test_flag class]])) 
{

    MKAnnotationView *pinView = nil; 

    if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) 
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"PinId1";
        pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc]
                                          initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin1"] autorelease];
        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        pinView.animatesDrop = YES;
        [pinView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"flg.png"]];
        [pinView setSelected:YES animated:YES];

    } 
    else 
    {
        [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
    }
    return pinView;
}
else if(([annotation isKindOfClass:[Distance1 class]])) 
{
    MKAnnotationView *pinView = nil; 

    if(annotation != mapView.userLocation) 
    {
        static NSString *defaultPinID = @"PinId4";
        pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];
        if ( pinView == nil ) pinView = [[[MKAnnotationView alloc]
                                          initWithAnnotation:annotation reuseIdentifier:@"pin4"] autorelease];

        pinView.canShowCallout = YES;
        [pinView setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"Circle_Grey.png"]];
        [pinView setSelected:YES animated:YES];

    } 
    else 
    {
        [mapView.userLocation setTitle:@"I am here"];
    }
    return pinView;
}
```

When I touch the map, both `MKAnnotationView` are pointed but they do not show the title. What is the reason? Please help me to find.

Comment: follow the SO answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589181/displaying-pin-with-title-annotation-once-map-loads

Answer (score 0):

You missed to write `title` method in `Test_flag` class.

Comment: I have added NSString *title and @property,@synthesize also in Test_flag class

Comment: When you are adding annotation to the map, set the value to title. For now hardcode return temp value to check.

Comment: that also I did like  test_flag.title = @"Distance";
            test_flag.subtitle = @"0.0";

Comment: Display the code from where you are adding annotations to the map.

Comment: Test_flag *test_flag = [[Test_flag alloc] init]; 
            test_flag.title = @"Distance";
            test_flag.subtitle = @"0.0"; 
            [mapView addAnnotation:test_flag]; after that am setting the coordinate like test_flag.coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2DMake(28.458586, 77.109126);