# MapKit pin title not showing

Tags: xcode, mapkit

The location is working but the title isn't appearing, most strange.

```
location.latitude = (double) 51.501468;
location.longitude = (double) -0.141596;

// Add the annotation to our map view
MapViewAnnotation *newAnnotation = [[MapViewAnnotation alloc] initWithTitle:@"ABC" andCoordinate:location];
[self.mapView addAnnotation:newAnnotation];
// [newAnnotation release];
```

MapViewAnnotation.h

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>

@interface MapViewAnnotation : NSObject <MKAnnotation> {

NSString *title;
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

}

@property (nonatomic, copy) NSString *title;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate;

- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d;

@end
```

and MapViewAnnotation.m

```
 #import "MapViewAnnotation.h"

 @implementation MapViewAnnotation

 @synthesize title, coordinate;

 - (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d {
title = ttl;
coordinate = c2d;
return self;
 }

 @end
```

[newAnnotation release] is remmed out to keep the ARC happy :-)
Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

This did the trick:

```
[mapView selectAnnotation:newAnnotation animated:YES];
```

previously the title would only show if you clicked on the Pin.

Answer (score 0):

you call annotation delegates [refer this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5589181/displaying-pin-with-title-annotation-once-map-loads), [mapkit-example-in-iphone](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/mapkit-example-in-iphone/)

Answer (score 0):

That code looks fine (except for the non-standard implementation of the `init` method).

The most likely reason the title (callout) isn't appearing is that in your `viewForAnnotation` delegate method, you are not setting `canShowCallout` to `YES` (it defaults to `NO`).

In the `viewForAnnotation` delegate method, after you create the `MKAnnotationView`, set `canShowCallout` to `YES`.

*Unrelated* to the title/callout not showing, the `init` method in your `MapViewAnnotation` class should be implemented like this:

```
- (id)initWithTitle:(NSString *)ttl andCoordinate:(CLLocationCoordinate2D)c2d {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        title = ttl;
        coordinate = c2d;
    }
    return self;
}
```